# R data.table looping over columns to conditionally replace row values

Tags: r, data.table

Looking for what should be an incredibly simple solution. I'd like to conditionally replace a value in a row if it meets a given condition (less than zero), and I would like to do this for hundreds (twenty in the example) of columns each with 150 million rows. I'm on hour seven of trying every solution that I found on the stack, so please don't mark this as duplicate. :-)

Data:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1:1000), x=rnorm(1:1000,60,20))
```

Using an intuitive loop to create new columns:

```
## Create new variables
for(i in 50:70) {
  dt[, paste0("y", i) := i-x]
}
```

Simple command on a single column, works great:

```
dt$y60[dt$y60<0 ] <- 0
```

Place this inside of a loop and it fails:

```
for(i in 50:70) {
  dt$y[i][dt$y[i]<0] <- 0
}
```

What should be a simple DT approach, no luck:

```
for(i in 50:70) {
  dt[y[i]<0, y[i] := 0]
}
```

Trying an `ifelse()` approach, no luck:

```
for(i in 50:70) {
  dt$y[i] <- ifelse(dt$y[i] < 0, 0, dt$y[i])
}
```

Trying first to create a list, and then use `set()`, no dice:

```
list <- dt %>% dplyr:: select(starts_with("y"))
for(i in 50:70) {
  set(dt, i, list , 0)
}
```

My life is in your hands, thank you!!

Comment: maybe `dt[, (paste0("y", 50:70)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[x<0] <- 0; x}), .SDcols=paste0("y", 50:70)]` ?

Comment: Why loop? Why not just `dt[dt<0] <- 0`

Comment: @ chinsoon12 That was exactly it! Any chance you could elaborate on the processes going on in your solution? I'll happily upvote it. 

Thank you!

Comment: @MKR In this simple example that would be fine, and that solution was mentioned in another post. However, in the actual DT there are other variables that I do not want to replace, and I do not want to replace the entire column. edit: you noted this in your solution, thanks :-)

Comment: Probably you know already, but if you put the data in long form, no creative tricks are needed. `ydt = melt(dt, id="id", meas=paste0("y",50:70)); ydt[, value := value*(value >= 0)]` (And you could keep `x` and "other variables" in the original table. You don't need to keep all data in a single table in r.)

Comment: @Frank, thanks, in many cases that would be a good suggestion as well. Although in this case, there are 140 columns and 145 million rows. I'm not even sure my 20-core cluster would appreciate that approach. You're also correct that I could parse this out, although I'm setting up some infrastructure to apply this to more cases so it will be 'convenient' to keep it together without addition merges etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 using `:=`:

```
dt[, (paste0("y", 50:70)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[x<0] <- 0; x}), .SDcols=paste0("y", 50:70)]
```

Option 2 using `set`:

```
for (j in paste0("y", 50:70)) {
    set(dt, dt[,which(get(j) < 0)], j, 0)
}
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id=c(1:1000), x=rnorm(1:1000,60,20))
for(i in 50:70) {
    dt[, paste0("y", i) := i-x]
}
```

Comment: Note: Given your data size, might be that set becomes worth it for the speed

Comment: Instead of `lapply`, there's `.SD*(.SD >= 0)`

Comment: @Frank This will convert the whole data to a matrix, twice. `lapply` usual the preferable/recommend method. Guess this is related https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do's-and-Don'ts#5-dont-use-colsums-use-lapply-on-sd

Comment: @DavidA Ah, d'oh. I expected that but then checked `dt[, str(.SD*(.SD >= 0))]` and saw that it wasn't a matrix and thought I was in the clear, but nope, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to change value of columns starting with say `y` then a solution can be to use `mutate_at` perform checking on only selected columns:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("y")), funs(ifelse(.<0,0,.)))
```

In case you want to perform checking on all columns, then below line should be good enough:

```
dt[dt<0] <- 0
```